# Interactive Bash Shell (TTY) from Bash Function

Tags: bash, docker, shell, kubernetes

So there are commands like `docker exec -t`, `docker-compose exec $CONTAINER /bin/bash`, `kubectl exec $POD_NAME -it /bin/bash` that I use to connect to an instance with a TTY that basically engages an interactive shell instance from my local terminal.

I had build aliases around these or other scripts, but I'm interested in turning these into functions now.

So previously, I might have had:

```
alias container=`...; docker-compose exec $CONTAINER /bin/bash;`
```

Where `...` is an arbitrary set of other bash commands necessary for the last statement. This successfully engaged the shell.

Now, I have:

```
function container {
    ...
    docker-compose exec $CONTAINER /bin/bash
}
```

Which seems to hang in a loop. I'm a beginner to understanding Linux/Unix systems. Could someone explain:
- How I can contain this within a multiline function in my `bash_profile` as opposed to an alias?
- What exactly is going on when I execute these commands? I understand an alias is only a stored value...how does that affect the behavior here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what code you have in the `...` it might be what causes the error.
But her what i have done and it worked.

Here is what i changed:
I  used `docker` instead of `docker-compose`.
I added `-it` flags.
Also added `CONTAINER=$1` to get the container name as parameter.

```
function container {                        
        CONTAINER=$1                        
        echo "Your code here"                     
        docker exec -it $CONTAINER /bin/bash
}
```

Just put it in `.bashrc` or `.bash_profile` and it works.
As far as i understand `.bash_profile` and `.bashrc` are just shell script that get sourced into current session any time you open new shell.
So Any function you put inside will be available as if you run it in regular script.

You can also source more files inside them to keep them clean and make your custom commands and functions more portable.
Like this:`.bash_profile`

```
# dotfile dir is actually a git repo that i clone to any new machine i use.
# And Add this line only to my .bash_profile
if [ -f ~/dotfiles/.bash_customize ]; then
    . ~/dotfiles/.bash_customize
fi
```